# Populate Select Box from XML using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I've seen several examples here on how to do this and have successfully implemented others that use attributes. This time I'm given XML without attributes and i'm trying to figure out how to populate my select list from the node values instead of attributes. I keep getting objects returned instead of text. What am I doing wrong here?

code:

```
var code_data;
$.get('Book.xml', function (data) {
    code_data = data;
    var that = $('#BookDropdown');
    $('Book', code_data).each(function () {
        $('<option />', {
            text: $('BookName').val('label'),
            value: $('BookID').val('value')
        }).appendTo(that);
    });
}, 'xml');
```

XML:

```
<BookList>
  <Book>
    <BookName>Book One</BookName>
    <BookID>1</BookID>
  </Book>
  <Book>
    <BookName>Book Two</BookName>
    <BookID>2</BookID>
  </Book>
  <Book>
    <BookName>Book Three</BookName>
    <BookID>3</BookID>
  </Book>
  <Book>
    <BookName>Book Four</BookName>
    <BookID>4</BookID>
  </Book>
  <Book>
    <BookName>Book Five</BookName>
    <BookID>5</BookID>
  </Book>
</BookList>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are accessing `BookName` and `BookID` is wrong. . .use following code instead.
`

```
var code_data;
  $.get('Book.xml', function(data) {
    code_data = data;
    var that = $('#BookDropdown');
    $('Book', code_data).each(function() {
      $('<option />', {
        text: $('BookName',this).text(),
        value: $('BookID',this).text()
      }).appendTo(that);
    });
  }, 'xml');
```

`

Comment: ahhh I see!  Thank You Ravikiran!